# JQuery | Check mouseMove in PDF <object>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

Im working on a script that checks how long an user has been innactive.
When the user is not moving their mouse for 10 minutes, it should redirect to the homepage.

The script shown, is to reset the setTimeout of the reloadpage to 0. This triggers when a user does any action.

Now the script is working just fine, BUT not triggering when im hovering my pdf object

// html code

```
<object id="pdfBox" data="media/pdf1/pdf1.pdf#toolbar=0" type="application/pdf" style="padding-right:75px; height: 100vh;width: 100%;">
   <p>Alternative text - include a link <a href="media/pdf1/pdf1.pdf">to the PDF!</a></p>
</object>
```

// my normal script

```
$(window).on('click mousemove mouseover keydown change', function() {
 _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
});
```

// how i tried to access my object

```
var boxvar = $("#pdfBox").init();
$(boxvar).on('click mousemove mouseover keydown change', function() {
  console.log("hi");
 _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
});
```

Every way i try to acces my object using javascript seems to fail, is it even possible?

Comment: please check this: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/f238hchm/1/

Comment: Hey @Tegito123 the script still says im 'inactive' while im hovering my <object type="pdf">